# What's the alternative command in AHK_L or AHK Basic as @HotKeyPressed in AutoItv3?

Tags: autohotkey, key-bindings

The background is I'm writing [a small script](https://github.com/voidmous/PUF/tree/devel) to pop up an application window with hotkeys, both application and hotkey can be customized with an `ini` file. I've completed it with AutoItv3 and it works fine for me. Now I'm considering re-implementing it with AHK_L(preferred) or Basic, yet I can't find the alternative way of doing `dynamically binding hotkeys` in AHK while in AutoIt `@HotKeyPresssed` is helpful as discussed [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/63526-hotkeyset-function-parameters/).

My code in AutoItv3 is basically like this:

```
For 1 to $NumberOfKeys
   $Key = ReadOneKeyFromIniFile()
   HotKeySet($Key,"_Main")
Next
Func _Main()
   $AppKeyBind = @HotKeyPressed
   $Parameters = ReadParametersFromIniFileAccordingToKey($AppKeyBind)
   PopUpWindowWithHotKey($Parameters)
EndFunc
```

`@HotKeyPressed` used here is mainly aiming to break the limitation that `HotKeySet()` can't bind `$Key` to function `_Main` **with parameters**.

Comment: I'm [German](https://theweek.com/article/index/245258/8-of-our-favorite-ridiculously-long-german-words) and even I find the function name `ReadParametersFromIniFileAccordingToKey` ridiculously long!

Comment: I'm a newbie programmer and I'm not sure what the right pseudo code is, and I'm from chinese mainland, and ... lol, got your humor!
I'll look into your answer btw.

Comment: I think you can imagine that function names containing 8 words (39 characters) are pretty hard to parse, even if they are in [PascalCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx). This especially applies to people like us (non native speakers). A good name imho would be something like `ReadIni` or `FetchParameters`, depending on its purpose and your personal preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [A_ThisHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Variables.htm#ThisHotkey).
Example usage:

```
a::
b::
c::
    MsgBox, You pressed %A_ThisHotkey%.
return
```